# refactoring a function that sorts with consideration for initial articles

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, filter, refactoring

I've got a function that does what I want it to do, but it's really, really ugly. Looking for ways to not necessarily make it faster, but maybe make it a little less ugly, more generic, and overall more maintainable.

```
<?php

// unordered list
$list = Array(
    0 => 'My Images',
    1 => 'Text Alignment',
    2 => 'Your New Post',
    3 => 'The More Tag',
    4 => 'The Average Post',
    5 => 'The Paginated'
);

// Desired output:
//  Array(
//      4 => 'The Average Post',
//      3 => 'The More Tag',
//      0 => 'My Images',
//      5 => 'The Paginated',
//      1 => 'Text Alignment',
//      2 => 'Your New Post'
//  )

function alphabetical_sort_with_initial_articles($array) {
    $temp_results = [];
    $results = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $value_arr = explode(' ', $value);
        if($value_arr[0] === 'The') { // need to make this dynamic: the|The|etc.
            $initial_article = array_shift($value_arr);
            $temp_results[$key] = array(
                implode(' ', $value_arr),
                $initial_article
            );
        } else {
            $temp_results[$key] = array(
                implode(' ', $value_arr),
                false
            );
        }
    }

    uasort($temp_results, function($a, $b) {
        return ($a[0] > $b[0]);
    });

    foreach($temp_results as $key => $value) {
        $results[$key] = trim($value[1] . ' ' . $value[0]);
    }

    return $results;
}

print_r($list);
echo "------------------------\n";
print_r(alphabetical_sort_with_initial_articles($list));

//josh@lear:~/Development/PHP/$ time php lists.php
//Array
//(
//    [0] => My Images
//    [1] => Text Alignment
//    [2] => Your New Post
//    [3] => The More Tag
//    [4] => The Average Post
//    [5] => The Paginated
//)
//------------------------
//Array
//(
//    [4] => The Average Post
//    [3] => The More Tag
//    [0] => My Images
//    [5] => The Paginated
//    [1] => Text Alignment
//    [2] => Your New Post
//)
//
//real  0m0.032s
//user  0m0.017s
//sys   0m0.013s
```

Comment: You want http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rjdown ah, I wasn't aware of that stack exchange. thanks for pointing that place out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where you are getting the titles, and assume you are only filtering on 'the ' in the beginning.  But this is very simple solution.

```
if (substr(strtoupper($title),0,4) == 'THE '){$key = substr($title,4);}else{$key=$title;}
$list[$key] = $title;

ksort($list);
```

if you are being passed an array:

```
foreach($list as $title){
    if (substr(strtoupper($title),0,4) == 'THE '){$key = substr($title,4);}
    $temp[$key] = $title;
}
ksort($temp);
$list = $temp;
```

if you need a numeric array index

```
foreach($list as $title){
    if (substr(strtoupper($title),0,4) == 'THE '){$key = substr($title,4);}else{$key=$title;}
    $temp[$key] = $title;
}
ksort($temp);
$list = array();
foreach ($temp as $title){
  $list[] = $title;
}
```

if you need the original  numeric array index

```
foreach($list as $key => $title){
    if (substr(strtoupper($title),0,4) == 'THE '){$sort= substr($title,4);}else{$sort=$title;}
    $temp[$sort] = array($key,$title;);
}
ksort($temp);
$list = array();
foreach ($temp as $title){
  $list[$title[0]] = $title[1];
}
```

Comment: essentially, yeah-- just ordering without regard for the 'the ''s at the beginning of the strings in an array. this is pretty succinct, and way more maintainable. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... none of these maintain index association like my example. They're also all bugged, you'll need to add an `else { $key = $title; }` to each.

Comment: It's here: `$temp[$key] = $title;` but $key is never set if the title has no "the ". `substr` is certainly not "much more" efficient than preg_replace, though I agree it is slightly faster on its own. But probably not when used twice, with a strtoupper as well... besides, he stated speed was not the issue, maintainability and ugliness was, and I think preg_replace in comparison excels at fixing this. There's still the issue of key association, that temp array really messes things up.

Comment: @rjdown  In the PHP manual they warn about using preg_match when simpler functions will do,  they recommend  `strpos()` and `strstr()`.   And the case insensitive modifier cannot be more efficient than `strtoupper()`, I would guess case is a wash.  But the preg regex engine is major overhead, oterwise the PHP manual would not include this Tip:  "Tip

Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster."   http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I think you're missing the point. `$list[$key] = $title;`. $key is not being set by your code correctly for half the elements. And yes, strpos and strstr are much faster at their job compared to preg_match (as per the manual). Do not confuse these with substr, I realise they are similarly-named but they do very different things.

Comment: @rjdown Thank you for catching my error, I have corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick go:

```
uasort($list, function($a, $b) {
    $a = preg_replace('/^the /i', '', $a);
    $b = preg_replace('/^the /i', '', $b);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

though it's a little unclear what you're trying to do. Seems like you're just ordering alphabetically while ignoring the "the "s.

Comment: ignoring the 'the ''s is exactly what I'm going after.

Comment: Oh, now I see.  At first I did not get this at all.   You put a band aid on the OP's code.  I never looked at the original code.  Just looked at the "unordered list" and "desired output".  I find that if I look at others code, it corrupts my thinking.